# BeautifulSoup 4 Extracting Data from url

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm writing a python 3.3.3 program used to scrape values taken from this webpage: http://www.oanda.com/currency/live-exchange-rates/ . I'm taking the example of GBP/USD. I use BeautifulSoup 4 and I have the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://www.oanda.com/currency/live-exchange-rates/"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

g_data = soup.find_all("div",{"class": "inline value right"})
for item in g_data:
     print (item.contents)
```

When I run it I get a long list of values and one of those is the GBP/USD value i'm interested in:

```
['\n', <span class="inline_int" id="GBP_USD-b-int"></span>, <span class="pip"     
id="GBP_USD-b-pip"></span>, <span class="inline_pipette" id="GBP_USD-b-ette"></span>, '\n']
```

The problem is that the values are not printed in the list.

Note: if I replace the print function with `print (item.contents[0].text)` or `print(item.contents[0].find_all())`, I get attribute errors: `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'text'` and `AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'find_all'`. So I could not use these functions to get the desired result.

Since when you inspect the element on that webpage, you can clearly see that there is a value printed:

```
<span id="GBP_USD-b-int" class="inline_int" style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102);">1.65</span>
<span id="GBP_USD-b-pip" class="pip" style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102);">68</span>
<span id="GBP_USD-b-ette" class="inline_pipette" style="color: rgb(102, 102, 102);">8</span>
```

I want to know how to show those values (1.65,68 and 8). I only need to show those values, as I am going to use a parser to extract those values.

Comment: These values are not in the page source. They are coming through separate request/response. See the requests form the web pages are made in firebug(firefox) or developer tools(chorme).

Comment: You're also performing the `.text` method on a `\n` character and since you're using [0] as your index. As you can see the first item in the list is simply a newline character.

Comment: @salmanwahed So is there a way in Python to get around this problem and extract the page with the values in the span?

Comment: One way is to find the `request url` by which the the webpage is getting data. in firebug go to the `Net` tab or in chorme go to `Network` tab and see the requests. see the `xmlhttp` requests in `XHR` tag and analyze the response. If you find a useful response then use that `request url` for fetching data.